# Group chat room software / plugin for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, team-foundation-server

I am trying to find a campfire-like plugin for SharePoint.

We use SharePoint as part of our TFS installation. Everyone logs in with their AD, it all links in nicely to Visual Studio and everything's great. But one thing we are missing is a chat room for all the developers to hang out in, to share information quickly, announce deployments, that kind of thing.

Has anyone had any luck finding something appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Lync Server is the new version of office communicator server, which provides group chat functionality. Group chat is very much what you describe in your question. I hope this gives you [more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Lync_Server)

There is no direct SharePoint integration with this and it requires a desktop plugin, however there is some [3rd party integration](http://www.formicary.com/sharepoint).